# Firefox doesn't restore cursor property

Tags: css, flash, firefox, cursor

I'm working with webcams and have experienced a weird issue.

I have a flash object with my webcam video, and I have put a div over it (with absolute positioning), as a button to toggle the video. The HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <object></object>
  <div class="camicon"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.camicon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-image: url('../../images/broadcast/webcam-icon.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The problem now is that, in Firefox, cursor is not restored to its default value (i.e. the arrow) while cursor has left the icon AND stays on the flash object. However, cursor is restored properly when it moves outside the flash object.

This doesn't happen on Chrome, so I guess this may be some annoying bug.

Does anyone know something about this? I have tried lots of possible fixes for it, but no success so far.

More info:

- Ubuntu 11.10 32bits
- Firefox 13.0.1
- Flash 11.2.202.236

Comment: While googling, I've seen a thread with a similar question, but nobody answered to him: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1853205

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any code to test it, but I would think something like this should work to help force the point (maybe this is one of the solutions you already tried):

```css
#container {
    cursor: auto; /* or "default" */
}


#container div.camicon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-image: url('../../images/broadcast/webcam-icon.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried it, and it didn't work :( The bug is related to the flash object, not the container.